# Use javascript to show tables via select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display a certain table when it's selected from the select drop down. This is so far I have got, but it's not working

javascript;

```
var opt = document.getElementById('select');

opt.onchange = function() {
document.getElementById('t1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('t2').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('t3').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('t4').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('t' + this.value).style.display = '';
```

html

```
<select name="select" id="select">
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Please Select</option>
<option value="1">CAT Requests</option>
<option value="2">Stop Bulk Messages</option>
<option value="3">PO - Deposit Transfer</option>
<option value="4">PO - Address Change</option>
</select>


<table id="t1">
<tr>
<td>Etisalat Number</td>
<td><input type="text" name="eti_num"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>CAT Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="cat_name"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Artist Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="art_name"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Language</td>
<td><input type="text" name="lang"/> </td>
</tr>
</table>

<table id="t2">
<tr>
<td>Etisalat Number</td>
<td><input type="text" name="eti_num"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Comment</td>
<td><input type="text" name="comment"/> </td>
</tr>
</table>

<table id="t3">
<tr>
<td>Etisalat Number</td>
<td><input type="text" name="eti_num"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Amount</td>
<td><input type="text" name="amt"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Reason to Transfer</td>
<td><input type="text" name="reason_to_transfer"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Comment</td>
<td><input type="text" name="comment"/> </td>
</tr>
</table>    

<table id="t4">
<tr>
<td>Etisalat Number</td>
<td><input type="text" name="eti_num"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Customer Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="cus_name"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Correct Address</td>
<td><input type="text" name="corr_name"/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Comment</td>
<td><input type="text" name="comment"/> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I don't get why the tables are hidden on pageload and shown when the relevant option is selected.

Comment: try document.getElementById('t' + this.value).style.display = 'block';  or just change the <option value="1">..</option> to <option value="t1">..</option>

Comment: so on pageload what do you want to happen? and when the option is selected you want it to display the proper table correct?

Comment: *It's not working* is not a question.

Comment: you still have not said what you are looking for. it's hard to help when you don't actually have a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

http:/http://jsfiddle.net/tjC59/1/

```
<body>
    <select name="select" id="select" onchange="changeSelection()"><!--Added the onchange Function -->
        <option value="0">Please Select</option>
        <option value="1">CAT Requests</option>
        <option value="2">Stop Bulk Messages</option>
        <option value="3">PO - Deposit Transfer</option>
        <option value="4">PO - Address Change</option>
    </select>
    <table id="t1">
        <tr>
            <td>Etisalat Number</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="eti_num"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CAT Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="cat_name"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Artist Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="art_name"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Language</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lang"/> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="t2">
        <tr>
            <td>Etisalat Number</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="eti_num"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Comment</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="comment"/> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="t3">
        <tr>
            <td>Etisalat Number</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="eti_num"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Amount</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="amt"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Reason to Transfer</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="reason_to_transfer"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Comment</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="comment"/> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
    <table id="t4">
        <tr>
            <td>Etisalat Number</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="eti_num"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Customer Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="cus_name"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Correct Address</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="corr_name"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Comment</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="comment"/> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- Good Practice - Always put your scripts at the end of the Html Body -->
    <script>
        //When the option is changed 
        var changeSelection = function () {
            //Hide all of the elements
            hideAll();
            //If the select value is > 0 (is valid)
            if (document.getElementById("select").value > 0) {
                //Set the element display to "block" (block is typically the default display type)
                document.getElementById("t" + document.getElementById("select").value).style.display = "block";
            }
        };
        //Function to hide all of the elements
        var hideAll = function () {
            //Loop through the elements
            for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                //Hide each one
                document.getElementById("t" + i).style.display = "none";
            }
        };
        //This function automaticaly executes when the page is loaded
        (function () {
            //Hide all of the elements
            hideAll();
        })()
    </script>
```

Comment: don't have 15 rep points to vote up... will vote up the answer as soon as i get 15 rep points...:D works like magic...

btw what went wrong in my code?

Comment: I've updated the code above and included comments explaining everything that I did here.  Hopefully this will help you out.  If you need any more help, or are unsure about something I did, don't hesitate to ask and I can explain further.  Thanks.

Comment: why is the java-script recommend to be added in the end of code and not in the head? @HowardRenollet

Comment: So it will load after the DOM finishes loading.  It prevents problems that could occur when automatically executing code when the page loads.  Notice above, the self executing anonymous function to hide the elements *(function (){//do stuff})();*, this would likely fail if it was in the head because the html elements would be undefined at that point in the document.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the default option is selected on pageload. So your onchange handler is fired with the value "Please Select" on pageload. What this does is that it hides all the tables and `document.getElementById('tPleaseSelect')` is not found, and hence no table is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I have a fiddle working that displays the tables on page load. Then when one of the tables is selected it shows just that table. Your above code works fine besides the fact that you were missing a close `};`.

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/stewbydoo/NjjxT/)

Answer (score 0):

You can display by the below code slight modification on your code:

```
<select name="select" id="select" onchange="displayTable();">



<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayTable() {
        var opt = document.getElementById('select');

        opt.onchange = function () {
            document.getElementById('t1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('t2').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('t3').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('t4').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('t' + this.value).style.display = '';
        };
    }
</script></head>
```